# Constant Length Line moving within an Oval Boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

A curved line segment of constant curved length $ L=PQ$ rotates around fixed point O contacting a smooth rigid surface. "Diameters" $P-Q,P1-Q1,P2-Q2...$ are sliding on, or skinning along the surface. They bend or twist according to line curvature of the surface.

Can we define some examples of line/surface combination of given boundary length $\lambda L $ for constant $\lambda ?$

Only a trivial case of a straight diameter line L sweeping out around center point $O$ a circle C in a plane with $ \lambda =\pi $  comes to mind. So also is the case with geodesic circles using geodesic polar coordinates where a pole at center is fixed and radii are of fixed length in rotation without sliding.

EDIT 1:

To start with a simple spherical cap when $O$ is not at the center of the cap we have differential arcs $s_1,s_2$ on opposite sides of O

$$ d \psi= \frac{ds_1}{\rho}=\frac{ds_2}{L-\rho}=\frac{d(s_1+s_2)}{L} $$

where $\psi$ is rotation from a fixed reference line, $\rho$ is radial length OP in the manner of geodesic polar coordinates. But could not proceed further.

Thanks in advance for all comments about handling such situations.

[image]

Comment: The example given gives the impression that the "sliding" segment (maybe "rotating" would be better) changes its shape...

Comment: Thanks. While rotating $PQ$ changes shape. Please comment about this edit.